# do TV broadcasts provide localized advertisements by altering the TV photo

Tags: broadcasting

In TV broadcasts of football matches (soccer matches) there are often long displays along the side of the football field that show advertisements. I guess that these displays are made up of electronic lamps, but in the future it might be possible (albeit technically very difficult) to add the advertisements by just post-processing the TV photo in a computer. In this way TV companies could broadcast international football matches with localized advertisement, for instance with one type of advertisement per country.

Do you know of any examples from TV broadcasts of sport events, where image post-processing have altered the TV photo to adjust for different advertisements?

Comment: The technology already exists (see http://www.vizrt.com/, a Norwegian company). I just wonder how they will show ads to the physical audience in the stadium :) +1 Nice idea though!

Comment: It is realistic to have defined spaces with adverts in for the crowd that can be overwritten in post-processing for televised markets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was already done and seems to be done regularly in certain sports. [Here](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-8039371.html) is a (German, sorry) article from 1998 where this was done in the UEFA cup game Glasgow Rangers vs AC Parma. There where localized advertisements in Germany and Italy placed on areas originally pink. [Here](http://www.accessmylibrary.com/article-1G1-274114770/virtual-advertising-sports-events.html) is the only English summary article on the subject that I found using a quick search.

@Mick79 the question was for advertisements per country which is a good idea. In the given UEFA cup game for Germany they showed ads for a nation wide hardware store and a brewery selling nation wide which wouldn't have paid for ad space in this match (Scotland vs. Italy) if they had to pay for the whole international reach (I would think). Targeted advertisement is always better.

Answer (score 3):

What a great idea -- you should enter the marketing field!

I don't know if anyone has thought to do localized advertisements yet, but image post-processing is routinely used, at least on American football broadcasts, to track the field and the marker lines thereupon, so as to provide various forms of in-game analysis.

If they can do that, I'm sure they could turn the field-side displays into green screen to show localized TV advertisements on, but if that happens, then the spectators at the physical location aren't able to see the advertisements! So some of this probably has to do with whether it's the TV station or the Stadium that sells those ads, and whether or not localized broadcast ad revenue would be more lucrative than installed non-processed ads.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the point that there are also local spectators at the physical location. If they only  see some mono-colour displays they will not see any ads.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree and don't believe you should get into marketing.

The point of advertising at big events like soccer matches is to generate cash for the club and exposure for the big brands.

small localised audiences equals small business' and small business budgets.

the clubs will ALWAYS prefer huge, household brand names who can afford to pay the premium for national/international exposure.

Nike paying (for example) £1m is a done deal. One transaction, large amount of money, done.
Organising several sales to many many small companies across the country is both time consuming, resource intensive and a headache. What if for example noone in newcastle wants to buy advertising that week?

The other factor is brand dilution. Big name clubs who get national tv coverage want to be associated with huge names like Nike, Addidas, Microsoft, Audi etc. They don't want "Jim's TV Repairs" or "East Sussex Motors". It makes them look big to have big names and the opposite is also true.

There are so many factors as to why this is a bad idea.

Comment: in the question there is no claim saying that such post-processed advertisements are a good thing. The question was just about if such advertisements exist.

Comment: No, but in one of the answers the author suggested that the original poster should go into marketing and that it was a great idea.

Comment: This post does not answer the question, which was more about the feasibility of adding the advertisements in post processing, not about whether or not it is a good idea.